# Conversion of coordinate systems. Unity. 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

2D Game.

Given specific points(x,y) both vary from 0  to 600. From the topleft corner.

How to covert the view so all instantiated objects wouldnt just appear in one corner. It would adjust to the camera.(the aspect ration)

Comment: Could you please clarify your question. Do you want to convert from screen space to world space? If so, there are methods available for that. Or is it sth else?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer questions without details. But you probably need to try

```
Instantiate(YourGameObject, Camera.main.transform.position);
```

to create a game object at camera's position, to move right/left and up/down just add another vector to the second parameter.

If you wanna use normalized coordinates just map them by manipulating the equation `A1 / A2 = B1 / B2`, but it's harder and you shouldn't.